# Movement of sperm to the egg

Tags: human-biology

> Sperm swims through semen and reaches the haploid egg in the oviduct during fertilisation.

- Once the sperm reaches the cervix, through what does the sperm swim through to reach the egg?
- Is the uterus completely filled with a fluid that allows the movement of the sperm, or does the sperm only swim through the endometrium (uterine lining)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once the sperm reaches the cervix, through what does the sperm swim
>   through to reach the egg?

It swims through the cervical mucus. Human sperm swim in a [straight path](http://www.reproduction-online.org/content/53/2/259.full.pdf+html) in cervical mucus.

> Is the uterus completely filled with a fluid that allows the movement
>   of the sperm, or does the sperm only swim through the endometrium
>   (uterine lining)?

Yes, the uterus is completely filled with uterine fluid. They are attacked by many leukocytes while being helped by various contractions.

I would suggest reading the [Suarez 2006](http://humupd.oxfordjournals.org/content/12/1/23.full) review. It has very nice information of all stages of sperm moment.